# My SQL request do not return me the same thing in localhost and in prod

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with one of my SQL request which does not return me the same thing when I work on localhost and when I work in prod environment. Could you tell me what's wrong with it?

I want to retrieve all the users contacted by one user order by the latest sent or received message.

```sql
SELECT member_id AS id, username, profile_picture, creation_date      
                            FROM (SELECT sender_id AS member_id, username, profile_picture, messages.creation_date
                                  FROM project_5_messages AS messages
                                  INNER JOIN project_5_users_parameters AS users_parameters ON users_parameters.id = messages.sender_id
                                  INNER JOIN project_5_users_profiles AS users_profiles ON users_parameters.id = users_profiles.user_id
                                  WHERE recipient_id = :user_id  AND messages.creation_date = (SELECT MAX(messages2.creation_date)
                                                                                                FROM project_5_messages AS messages2
                                                                                                WHERE messages2.sender_id = messages.sender_id)
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT recipient_id AS member_id, username, profile_picture, messages.creation_date
                                  FROM project_5_messages AS messages
                                  INNER JOIN project_5_users_parameters as users_parameters ON users_parameters.id = messages.recipient_id
                                  INNER JOIN project_5_users_profiles AS users_profiles ON users_parameters.id = users_profiles.user_id
                                  WHERE sender_id = :user_id AND messages.creation_date = (SELECT MAX(messages2.creation_date)
                                                                                            FROM project_5_messages AS messages2
                                                                                            WHERE messages2.recipient_id = messages.recipient_id))
                            AS members_contacted
                            WHERE creation_date = (SELECT MAX(messages2.creation_date)
                                                    FROM project_5_messages AS messages2
                                                    WHERE (messages2.recipient_id = members_contacted.member_id OR messages2.sender_id = members_contacted.member_id))
                            ORDER BY members_contacted.creation_date DESC
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: What is it returning in the two environments? Do the two environments have the same data?

Comment: Yes the 2 environment have the same data. In local, all the results are well returned but in prod rows are missing. I cannot figure out why...

Comment: Are the environments a strict 1:1? (i.e. the same data, the same tables, the same table schemas, etc.)?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have identical data.

Comment: Yes @War10ck, all the same cuz I uploaded the sql database data and schemas after I have made an export from localhost phpmyadmin

Comment: I'm going to add that there's got to be some kind of difference here or the queries wouldn't behave differently. Have you tried in a third environment that's cloned from one of the others? I'd clone A, test, then clone B and test, both on the same target machine. I bet you'd see a difference.

Comment: Same version of MySQL? Is this MariaDB vs MySQL? There's nothing in here that should behave differently, but you never know.

Comment: "Yes the 2 environment have the same data." -- well... no. How do you actually know that?

Comment: For one, the export and import process could have affected the data(base) in a way you didn't expect.